# Same column values in a partition as value in Rank 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

I want my SQL query to return the same column values in a partition as the value in the same column in the Rank 1 row of the partition.

Example :
Below is an example table :

```
Rank  Name  Class  PocketMoney
----  ----  -----  -----------
1       A     6         6
2       B     6         5
3       C     6         4
1       P     7         7
2       Q     7         6
1       R     8         8
2       S     8         7
3       T     8         6
4       U     8         5
```

I want the output of my SQL query to be like :

```
Rank  Name  Class  PocketMoney
----  ----  -----  -----------
1       A     6         6
2       B     6         6
3       C     6         6
1       P     7         7
2       Q     7         7
1       R     8         8
2       S     8         8
3       T     8         8
4       U     8         8
```

Is this possible in a SQL Query?

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.x so you can use window functions?

Comment: Does the "Example" is a table or a query result? Replace table-type example with CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts (and SQL query if it is the query output). *Is this possible in a SQL Query?* Of course.

Comment: @Barmar - Yes window functions are available

Comment: @Akina the first table in the example is the table and the second is what I want as the result of my SQL query

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [`first_value`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_first-value) to get the value from the first row of the partition.

```
select
  rank() over w,
  name,
  class,
  first_value(PocketMoney) over w as pocketmoney
from whatever
window w as (partition by class order by name asc)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want the same value as `rank = 1`, then use a conditional window function:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when rank = 1 then pocketmoney end) over (partition by class) as pocketmoney_1
from t;
```

Note:  This is a general solution that specifically answers your question.  It does what you want even if there is no `rank = 1` or if there are ranks less than 1.